# Rotate sprite in libgdx by following the position of finger on android

Tags: android, libgdx, rotation, sprite, jbox2d

I'm trying to rotate a sprite based upon where my finger is placed on the touch screen.

I have an arrow and i want the arrow to be pointing at my finger at all times as i'm drag it around over the screen.

I could easily set the sprite to any rotation using sprite.setRotation(angle)

How should i go about this?

Much appreciated if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(ax, ay)` is coordinates of the center of the arrow, and `(fx, fy)` is the coordinates of the finger, and `a` is the angle, here is some pseudocode:

```
dx = fx - ax
dy = fy - ay
if (dx == 0) {
    a = 90
    return
}
if (dy == 0) {
    a = 0
    return
}
//tan(a) == abs(dy) / abs(dx) therefore
a = arctan(dy / dx)
if (dx > 0 && dy > 0) {
    // do nothing, a is correct
} else if (dx > 0 && dy < 0) {
    a = 360 - a
} else if (dx < 0 && dy > 0) {
    a = 180 - a
} else {
    a = 180 + a
}
```

I didn't implement and test it yet, I'll do it later if there will be need

Comment: I tried implementing this but no luck.  I assumed                                           `tan(a) == abs(dy) / abs(dx)
a = arctan(dy / dx);`  Was an if statement.  I think i know where your going with this i'll keep @ it, I need to brush up on some trig.

Comment: I'm glad my answer is useful, sorry, it's ambiguous though, I had only a couple of minutes to write it